# Magento Site With Design Breaks in Production Environment

Tags: php, css, magento

I designed my Magento website on localhost and uploaded it to a production environment. When I was working with it on localhost, I had customized the design exactly to my liking. But now that it's on a production server everything has changed. An important static block is not loading into the page and my CSS output looks totally different.

I checked the "inspect element" tool, and the browser is canceling some of the CSS now that it's in a production environment. Why might this be?

Comment: How does live differ from local?  The first and most obvious one is that live and local will have different host names

Comment: Please explain the downvote. Also, what's the hostname got to do with it? The CSS files are loading just fine. I just have some design breaks.

Comment: The downvote is because the question is too vague and the possible solutions are too broad.  You've not provided enough information to answer the question.  The hostname is only one of many possible issues (if you coded in absolute URLs anywhere they'll break on live), but without more information from you it's impossible to rule that or anything else out.  You also haven't answered regarding in what ways live differs from local.  The answer will probably lie in one of those differences.

Answer (score 0):

I guess some of your links you implementet to your css and so on... you used hard link's like:
`c:\tmp\...` and not relativ link's  like: `../../blabla`! So now when the website is on the server some link's won't work anymore.

So i recommend you to look which link's doesn't work anymore, check the path if it is realativ and if not change it to a relativ link

Comment: No, all my links are relative.